# Mock property and call method in same class C#

Tags: c#, database, methods, mocking, moq

I have a class CommandExecutor which contains all commands(methods). I have to test a method which produces reports from a given 2 parameters.  Method uses a database to check if it produced yet.

**EDIT 1:**

property :

`public IEngine Engine { get; set; }`

IEngine interface:

```
ICommandExecutor CommandExecutor { get; }

IInputReader InputReader { get; }

IOutputWriter OutputWriter { get; }

IDatabase Database { get; }
```

CommandExecutor has a method Execute. I have other class (command factory) which creates ICommand. Engine reads input from a file for example, check if it is valid, split params etc... and creates an ICommand. Then CommandExecutor takes this ICommand and call method Execute. Method Execute has switch cases and every case returns a string if it success or if command is not successfull it throws an exepction. I want to unit test a method which depends on database. Can I mock this property Engine (in CommandExecutor) and call a method to check if it works correctly? Every method in CommandExecutor calls this.Engine.Database.....

Engine constructor:

```
public Engine(
    IInputReader reader,
    IOutputWriter writer,
    ICommandExecutor commandExecutor,
    IDatabase database)
{
    this.InputReader = reader;
    this.OutputWriter = writer;
    this.CommandExecutor = commandExecutor;
    this.CommandExecutor.Engine = this;
    this.Database = database;
```

}

```
var reportFound = this.Engine.Database.GetReport(name, model);
if (reportFound != null)
{
    throw new DuplicateEntryException(Constants.Duplicate);
}

Do something......

return string.Format(Constants.Test, model, name);
```

I mocked database(this method GetReport too), engine which working with mocked database. How can I mock a CommandExecutor engine property and call the method which I want to test?

Thanks

Comment: How does the ```CommandExecutor engine property``` look like? How does the class ```CommandExecutor``` look like? Please elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0):

Not really no, ask yourself why you want to do that, however. If you want to guarantee that a method in your class calls another method in the same class, it sounds like business logic is encapsulated within it that you don't want bypass. Refactor that out into a new class and slap an interface on it for that method, dependency inject that in there and now you can Mock it.